# C# How to send colorDialog value in 5bitRGB to a textBox?

Tags: c#, hex, rgb

So I'm creating an editor of a PS2 game. And this game has two "Systems" of colors.

The "normal" RGB R: 0 to 255 G: 0 to 255 B: 0 to 255.

And the or I think it is 5bitRGB R: 0 to 31 G: 0 to 31 B: 0 to 31.

And to make the color change in the game, I have to convert the chosen values in the colorDialog in Hexadecimal for example: R: 255 G: 176 B: 15 In Hexadecimal stands FFB00F.

And then later change these values in the "slots" of 3 bytes via Hex.

Beauty so far so good, but 5bitRGB only have "slots" of 2 bytes.

Example: 5bitRGB R: 31 G: 0 B: 0 in Hex 1F80.

And that's where I do not know what to do, because the colors of the normal RGB I can send the values in Hexadecimal to the textBox.

And then I saved these values textBox in "slots" of 3 bytes via Hex.

Meanwhile the slots for the 5bitRGB color change via Hex They are only "slots" of 2 bytes.

So I would have to send the converted colorDialog value to 5bitRGB for textBox in 2 bytes, is this really possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but I think it works ok (may need some refinement).

```
    public static void Main()
{
    int red = 0;
    int green = 255;
    int blue = 0;

    //convert to 5-bit values
    red = red >> 3;
    green = green >> 3;
    blue = blue >> 3;

    //position them correctly
    red = red << 8;
    blue = blue << 2;       
    int greenH = green >> 3;
    int greenL = green << 13;

    //add the 'always on' bit
    int fiveBitRGB = 0x80;

    //or them all together
    fiveBitRGB = fiveBitRGB | red | blue | greenH | greenL;
    fiveBitRGB = fiveBitRGB & 0xffff;

    Console.Write("Hex: {0:X4}", fiveBitRGB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert RGB to 5 bit RGB directly in this form?

```
int _8bitR = _5bitR * 31 / 255;
int _8bitG = _5bitG * 31 / 255;
int _8bitB = _5bitB * 31 / 255;
```

Because what I understood from your question is that you need these values, and Hexadecimal is not what you want.